# What is the right way to select <input type="radio"> in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My HTML code:

```
<div class="build-num">
  <div>
    <label class="radio-button">
      <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="1" required>1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-button">
      <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="2"><span>2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-button">
      <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="3"><span>3
    </label>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

In my JS file there is a function inside an object:

```
fromThirdFrameToFourth: function() {
  const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
  for (let i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    if (radioBtns[i].checked) {
      // it sees that the user checked one option and opens a new page;
    } else {
      // it alerts some text saying "Please choose one of the buildings";
    }
  }
}
```

I assume I don't know two things:

1. Am I actually choosing all input radios correctly? I cannot use just input, because there are other types of inputs in my HTML (type="text", "number" etc);
2. How to know if one of the radio buttons is checked?

What I was trying to implement is - if one of the radio check is chosen, then I let the user go to the next page, but if not, then he stays at the same page and I tell him in the alert that he has to choose one of the buildings.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I missed it while I was writing it here at the website. It is not working anyway. Do I correctly write my code, and what might be the reason, why it is not working?

Comment: I've updated my comment above for the second typo. :-) You're missing `.length` in your `for` loop condition.

Comment: After the typo is fixed, Your logic is wrong because you are going to alert even if the user has one checked.

Comment: so it should be "input[type='radio']" or "input[type=radio]"? Still not getting it, sorry

Comment: @epascarello Yes! That's what I'm getting. Apparently my logic is wrong. Can you point what actually it has to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I actually choosing all input radios correctly?

After the various typo fixes, yes, `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")` does select all of the radio buttons present in the DOM as of when you call it.

> How to know if one of the radio buttons is checked?

The best way would be to use the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#checked) as [shown by epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63564649/157247):

If you were looking for something that CSS didn't support, though, then the way you're doing it is close if you use a flag variable and exit early:

```
let atLeastOneMatch = false;
for (let i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    if (/*radioBtns[i] matches condition*/) {
        atLeastOneMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (atLeastOneMatch) {
    // One of them matched
} else {
    // None of them matched
}
```

There's also the `some` method on arrays you can use for this, even though `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`:

```
if (Array.prototype.some.call(radioBtns, function(btn) { return /* `btn` matches condition */; })) {
    // One of them matched
} else {
    // None of them matched
}
```

That calls `some` with `this` set to `radioBtns` passing in the callback function. The callback can be more concise, but I wrote the version above for clarity. Here's the more concise version:

```
if (Array.prototype.some.call(radioBtns, btn => /* `btn` matches condition*/)) {
    // One of them matched
} else {
    // None of them matched
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for dedicating your time for a newbie. What if I wanted to focus only radio buttons with the name <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="1" required>? I would write const radioBtns = document.getElementsByTagName("input[name="building-number"]")?

Comment: @someNewbie - You'd continue to use `querySelectorAll` rather than switching to `getElementsByTagName` (which can only use a plain tag name, like `input`). You can have more than one attribute selector in your CSS selector. An element has to satisfy all the criteria in order to match: `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio][name=building-number]")` You don't need quotes around `radio` and `building-number` if they're valid [CSS identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), otherwise you need `'` around them (in a `"`-quoted string) or `"` around them...

Comment: ...in a `'`-quoted string. Always including the quotes is fine too, e.g.: `document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'][name='building-number]")`

Comment: Oh, now I see how it works, I'll try to be more accurate at selecting something next time. Thank you

Comment: @someNewbie - Please note [epascarello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63564649/157247). For this specific check, `:checked` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code and a logic problem. You should not be using an else

How you should code it is a simple selector with `:checked`

```js
function check() {
  var selected = document.querySelector('.build-num input[type="radio"]:checked')
  if(selected) {
    console.log(selected);
  } else {
    console.log('no selection');
  }
}

document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener("click", check)
```

```html
<div class="build-num">
  <div>
    <label class="radio-button">
      <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="1" required>1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-button">
      <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="2"><span>2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-button">
      <input type="radio" name="building-number" value="3"><span>3
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="check">Check</button>
```

Comment: OMG how did I forget that `:checked` isn't just a jQuery thing?!? (For doubters: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#checked)