# Can I get element by value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I get element by value in JavaScript?
For example I have this input

```
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input"  value="this_value">
```

in javascript  I can get an element by name and id but how can I by value?

```
document.getElementById("this_value")
```

Comment: what you are expecting from get element by value?

Comment: Your radio button is missing a `name`. What are you doing with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564351/what-is-the-right-way-to-select-input-type-radio-in-dom

Answer (score 3):

Use an attribute selector

```
document.querySelector('[value="this_value"]')
```